# Highcharts stacked column stackLabels do not show when axis is reversed

Tags: highcharts

I'm having an issue where the stackLabels do not show on my yAxis when reversed is enabled.
See fiddle; https://jsfiddle.net/mattscotty/vhv8p77v/2/

```
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.chart( {
        chart: {
                renderTo :'container',
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Stacked bar chart'
        },
        exporting:{enabled:false},
        credits:{enabled:false},
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max:100,
            reversed:true, //Removing reversed fixes stack labels issue
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            stackLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                }
            }
        },
        plotOptions:{
                column:{
                    stacking:'normal'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Category I',
            data: [
                [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 14), 20],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 15), 30],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 16), 25],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 19), 10],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 20), 15]
            ]
        }, {
            name: 'Category II',
            data: [
                [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 14), 25],
                //[Date.UTC(2014, 5, 15), 10],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 16), 35],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 19), 25],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 20), 5]
            ]
        }, {
            name: 'Category III',
            data: [
                [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 14), 10],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 15), 20],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 16), 35],
                //[Date.UTC(2014, 5, 19), 25],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 20), 15]
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

Remove 'reversed' from yAxis and you will see it works fine, does anyone have a work around or suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked up the API documentation (see http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.stackLabels) and found something that may be useful for you.

Try adding `verticalAlign: bottom` to your `stackLabels` attribute. This will push your label to the inside bottom of your columns. If you wish, you can also add a value to `y` to move them directly under the column.

I'm curious why you're choosing to display your columns this way, as this presentation usually indicates negative value.

I hope this is helpful for you!

```
stackLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    style: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
    },
    // verticalAlign puts the stack labels at the bottom
    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
    // the y value moves the label outside the stack; 
    // note that "15" or higher in your fiddle will push it off the chart altogether
    y: 12
}
```

[image]

Comment: The fiddle was an intermediate stage between the fully finished chart but I noticed this issue.

Basically the axis will also be inverted (i.e. 100 at the top and 0 at the bottom) as we are showing percentages of loss.

100% is the maximum so the goal is to see what's eating in to our maximum of 100% (but in the fiddle we haven't yet finished the axis or total inversion).

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to have the labels still appear at the `0` mark for the axis you can either:

1. Pad the axis so that there is space in the plot area for the labels to be visible ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1cwp7wL8/1/)):

   ```
   yAxis: {
       min: -10, // Now there is space in the plot area for the labels to show
       // ...
   }
   ```
2. Allow the stack labels to show outside the plot area by setting the `crop` value ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1cwp7wL8/)):

   ```
   yAxis: {
       stackLabels: {
           crop: false, // Now the labels ignore being outside the plot area
           // ...
       }
   }
   ```

If you want them to appear at the top of the columns I suggest the `verticalAlign` and `y` approach detailed by @brightmatrix.

Comment: `crop`does not seam to be a valid property for `stackLabels` according to current API docu: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.stackLabels

Comment: @ErikKalkoken I do see that it is not specified, but the functionality still remains. I updated my fiddles to function so you can see the functionality. I'd say the `verticalAlign` and `y` approach is probably preferrable, but this offers an alternative.